# How can I order my record partials by rating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rating

I have a table of venues where each has many reviews and each review has a rating (1-5), my venue index page currently shows all the venues as partials in the order they were created with the oldest at the top how can I change this to display the venues with the highest average rating at the top?

My venues controller index currently looks like this:

```
  def index
    if
      @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas])
    else
      @venues = Venue.all
    end
  end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may find you need to show code of how you are generating that list.  Assuming you have a database it'll involve the words `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and the function `AVG()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Rails 3? Here's a starting point.

```
def index
  if
    @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas]).joins(:reviews).order("reviews.rating DESC")
  else
    @venues = Venue.joins(:reviews).order("reviews.rating DESC").all
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for having a look, I'm using rails 3 that code gives a can't convert Symbol into String error, I'm currently using @venue.reviews.average(:rating) to display the average rating for a venue on each venues show page

Comment: thats creating multiple copies of venue partials, if a venue has 3 reviews, so 3 ratings, its displaying 3 partials of that venue (the venue name is appearing 3 times on the index page and if a venue has 2 reviews its appearing twice). Is there something that can be done along the lines of .sort_by {@reviews.average(:rating)}? This doesn't work but im super new to this, thanks again